# How to list every records defined in a package?

Tags: oracle

I know how to list the objects defined in the database:

```
    select * from user_objects --where object_type='TYPE'
```

But I don't know how to list the records defined in the package.

You can run the query after having defined a type and a record a package.

```
CREATE TYPE t IS  OBJECT
(
    q    integer,
    b            INTEGER
);


CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE a as 
     type b is record(
             c integer
  );
end;
```

Only t will be printed.

Is there a way to list records defined in a package and if possible have its definition (name and type of the columns)

[code](https://dbfiddle.uk/X9MpB7uo)

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/wsYQsZIm

Comment: Which database version do you use, Pierre? ALL_PLSQL_TYPES (Alex suggested) was introduced in 12c.

Comment: Sure it does :) 18 > 12.